# Trying to find the most efficient way to 'travel' from coordinates where the coordinates are in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
          id    x_coordinate    y_coordinate    money   time (hr)
 0       545        0.676576    3.079094        4200    1.414706
 1      4138        0.262979    -0.769170        700    0.943230
 2      5281       -0.301234    -3.568590        200    1.314108
 3      4369       -0.585544    1.610388       11600    0.703957
 4      2173       -1.239105    3.168139       29200    0.666473
 5      9971       -1.556373    -1.624628      18700    0.776165
 6      2622       -1.747544     3.145381        100    0.842138
 7      4522       -1.923251    -2.695298      36700    0.186741
 8      7299       -2.697775    2.038365         500    0.469136
 9      5425       -4.443474    0.428256        1400    0.760269
```

Say the starting point is the first row. I want to manipulate the dataframe so that the second row is the  row whose coordinates are closest to the first row's and the third row is the row whose coordinates are closest to the second row's coordinates out of the remaining rows and so on.

Imagine the coordinates on a graph and I start at (0,0) for example. I am trying to find the most efficient way to 'travel' between these coordinates and end up at (0,0)
The output could be a list of coordinates sorted following the most efficient route for example. Or a new dataframe - just trying to figure out a way to solve this

So far I have tried to sort the df like this:

```
df = df.sort_values(["x_coordinate", "y_coordinate"], ascending = (False, True))
```

I have alternatively also tried to convert the df columns to lists using `df.to_list()` and then sorting them.

However, neither approach doesn't give the result I want. So any tips on how to go about manipulating a dataframe like this?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You cant simply sort a 2D vector by its coordinates to find which one is closer to each other. You have to use euclidean distance between the cross product of each point, then decide how to sort the array.

Comment: One way to do this is that you choose one of your coordinates (maybe the one with the smallest x value), and then sort the others based on the euclidean distance from that point. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Imagine the coordinates on a graph and I start at (0,0) for example. I am trying to find the most efficient way to 'travel' between these coordinates and end up at (0,0)

Comment: In that case Ill ask you to change the question to say `I am trying to find the most efficient way to 'travel' between these coordinates and end up at (0,0) `. Sorting a dataframe is not how you solve this. This is an algebra problem. Please make sure you reflect it in the question as the question is very misleading right now... so that people can assist you properly and the question doesnt get closed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I changed the title

Comment: Google "Traveling Salesman Problem"

Answer (score 1):

I think, sort won't be of any help. You will need to take a Euclidean distance of this points from your coordinates and then sort on it. That will give you the closest points.

This is what I tried quickly. See if this works. I didn't get a chance to verify the results.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import spatial

df = pd.DataFrame({
'id': [545,4138,5281,4369,2173,9971,2622,4522,7299,5425],
'x_coordinate': [0.676576, 0.262979, -0.301234, -0.585544, -1.239105,-1.556373,-1.747544,-1.923251,-2.697775,-4.443474],
'y_coordinate': [3.079094, -0.769170, -3.568590, 1.610388,  3.168139, -1.624628,3.145381,-2.695298,2.038365,0.428256],
})
print(df)

     id  x_coordinate  y_coordinate
0   545      0.676576      3.079094
1  4138      0.262979     -0.769170
2  5281     -0.301234     -3.568590
3  4369     -0.585544      1.610388
4  2173     -1.239105      3.168139
5  9971     -1.556373     -1.624628
6  2622     -1.747544      3.145381
7  4522     -1.923251     -2.695298
8  7299     -2.697775      2.038365
9  5425     -4.443474      0.428256

def shortest_neighbour(pt,nebr):
    tree = spatial.KDTree(nebr)
    dist = tree.query(pt,2)
    return dist[0][1],dist[1][1]

arr=df[['x_coordinate','y_coordinate']].to_numpy().reshape(len(df),2)
df[['Dist','Ord']]=pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda row : shortest_neighbour(arr[row.name],arr),axis = 1).tolist(),index=df.index)

print(df)

     id  x_coordinate  y_coordinate      Dist  Ord
0   545      0.676576      3.079094  1.917749    4
1  4138      0.262979     -0.769170  2.010435    5
2  5281     -0.301234     -3.568590  1.842167    7
3  4369     -0.585544      1.610388  1.689299    4
4  2173     -1.239105      3.168139  0.508948    6
5  9971     -1.556373     -1.624628  1.131783    7
6  2622     -1.747544      3.145381  0.508948    4
7  4522     -1.923251     -2.695298  1.131783    5
8  7299     -2.697775      2.038365  1.458912    6
9  5425     -4.443474      0.428256  2.374851    8


dfs=df.sort_values(by=['Ord','Dist'],ascending =[True,True])
print(dfs)

     id  x_coordinate  y_coordinate      Dist  Ord
6  2622     -1.747544      3.145381  0.508948    4
3  4369     -0.585544      1.610388  1.689299    4
0   545      0.676576      3.079094  1.917749    4
7  4522     -1.923251     -2.695298  1.131783    5
1  4138      0.262979     -0.769170  2.010435    5
4  2173     -1.239105      3.168139  0.508948    6
8  7299     -2.697775      2.038365  1.458912    6
5  9971     -1.556373     -1.624628  1.131783    7
2  5281     -0.301234     -3.568590  1.842167    7
9  5425     -4.443474      0.428256  2.374851    8
```

And one more thing I tired. Thats the distance from (0,0). See below if that is what you want.

```
df['Dist']=df.apply(lambda row: np.linalg.norm(np.zeros(2)-np.array([row.x_coordinate,row.y_coordinate])),axis = 1) 
print(df.sort_values(by=['Dist'],ascending =[True]))

     id  x_coordinate  y_coordinate      Dist
1  4138      0.262979     -0.769170  0.812884
3  4369     -0.585544      1.610388  1.713538
5  9971     -1.556373     -1.624628  2.249825
0   545      0.676576      3.079094  3.152551
7  4522     -1.923251     -2.695298  3.311122
8  7299     -2.697775      2.038365  3.381260
4  2173     -1.239105      3.168139  3.401836
2  5281     -0.301234     -3.568590  3.581281
6  2622     -1.747544      3.145381  3.598240
9  5425     -4.443474      0.428256  4.464064
```

Comment: I have actually considered this approach but doesn't this end up just sorting the df by how far it is from (0,0)? In this case, two coordinates can be the same distance from 0 but far away from each other whereas I am looking for the closest row's coordinates from the current row's coordinates

Comment: I have edited my answer... see if it is of any use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Using K nearest neighbors is definitely something I can use. My actual df is much larger so now I will try to apply it to that as I am trying to find an optimized route that has the most money per hour ratio within a time limit

Comment: I have also tried using ```scipy.pdist``` and ```scipy.squareform```  to calculate distances between all pairs of locations and cast it to a new df which shows the  distance between a given point and every other point in the dataframe